# How do I install and use three.js ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, three.js

So in all the THREE.js examples there is always stuff like

`import { FirstPersonControls } from './jsm/controls/FirstPersonControls.js';`

Is there a place where I can find all these libraries and their cdns? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/controls/FirstPersonControls.js

Answer (score 1):

All ES6 modules files from the examples directory are part of the `three` npm package and can be imported like so:

```
import { FirstPersonControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/FirstPersonControls .js';
```

Various CDNs like JSDelivr or unpkg can provide these modules by URLs like:

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122/examples/jsm/controls/FirstPersonControls.js
```

Comment: I tried using command prompt to install but it said npm doesn't exist. Also, the link given says: "Couldn't find the requested file /examples/jsm/controls/FirstPersonControls .js in three."

Comment: Sry, there was a typo in the link. If `npm` is missing, install node.js on your system.